# This is not permitted when the subquery follows Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having problem returning values to the column checklist percentage. It is giving error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=," The tables provided are just sample from thousands of rows which have many evaluation.

The tables are 2 and I extracted this sample from thousands of rows :

```
╔═════════╦═══════════════╗    
║ id      ║ value_integer ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣   
║ 2059064 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2064435 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2064889 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2064893 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2086272 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2134036 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2163046 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2175279 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2175279 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 2186928 ║ NULL          ║
╠═════════╬═══════════════╣
```

second table is :

```
╔═════════╦════════════╗
║ id      ║ evaluation ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2059064 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2064435 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2064889 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2064893 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2086272 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2128447 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2134036 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2163046 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2175279 ║ 50006      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2175279 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2186928 ║ 50004      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2190848 ║ 50001      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2190848 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2190848 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2190848 ║ 1          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2190848 ║ 1          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2222107 ║ 1          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2250093 ║ 1          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2250093 ║ 1          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2250093 ║ 50005      ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
║ 2250093 ║ 0          ║
╠═════════╬════════════╣
╚═════════╩════════════╝
```

The purpose is to calculate the percentage of evaluation selected / total evaluation. The evaluation 50001 is yes and 0 and 1 means not evaluated or not selected respectatively.

```
 UPDATE DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE
    SET D_ENERGY_REFERENCE.VALUE_INTEGER = (SELECT  (SELECT CAST(COUNT(EVALUATION) AS FLOAT)
                                                     FROM DB.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST
                                                     WHERE D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  = 50001
                                                     GROUP BY ID) / (SELECT CAST(COUNT(EVALUATION) AS FLOAT)
                                                                     FROM DB.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST
                                                                     WHERE D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1)
                                                                     GROUP BY ID) * 100
                                            FROM DB.D_CHECK_LIST D_CHECK_LIST 
                                            WHERE D_CHECK_LIST.ID IN (SELECT ID
                                                                      FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE  
                                                                      WHERE ID = D_CHECK_LIST.ID))
```

Comment: One of your sub queries is returning more than one record. Try running them seperately and youll find your issue

Comment: I did and am stuck. It gives value at separate select statement

Comment: Did you try both? The nested and the outer one?

Comment: If we put some tabbing in there, we can see that yuio don't even close all the brackets. But that subquery will definitely return multiple rows, as it's returning a row for every value of `ID` in the table `D_CHECK_LIST` that is also in the table `D_ENERGY_REFERENCE`. Perhaps you would be better showing your data and the expected results here.

Comment: Probably the case for `UPDATE  .. FROM  .. JOIN ..`

Comment: I omiited the closing bracket, it is in the code. I have put it in there. Still same result

Comment: The more I look at the query, the more I don't understand what its goal is. I didn't even realise till just now, but the subqueries in the subquery will even return multiple rows as there's a `GROUP BY` on `ID`. None of those queries use a lateral join to limit the returned results, so I actually have no idea what the OP is after at this stage.

Comment: You should try your sentences one at a time, and make sure each one gives you only one result. I think `SELECT ID FROM DB.D_ENERGY_REFERENCE WHERE ID = D_CHECK_LIST.ID` brings you more than 1 row, because you are using it with 'IN' instead of '='

Comment: @Lamu. I will post the table sample for you to see later.

Comment: @Lamu i have put the sample table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a update script as below-

**Note:** Please try with test data first.

```
UPDATE T
SET T.VALUE_INTEGER = A.Val
FROM D_ENERGY_REFERENCE T
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    ID,
    CASE 
        WHEN CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE
        (
            CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  = 50001 THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
            /
            CAST(COUNT(CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  NOT IN (0,1) THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL END) AS FLOAT)
        ) * 100 
    END AS Val
    FROM D_CHECK_LIST
    GROUP BY ID
)A ON T.ID = A.ID
```

Comment: I AM HAVING ERROR Incorrect syntax near ')'.  AT LINE 9   CASE WHEN D_CHECK_LIST.EVALUATION  = 50001 THEN EVALUATION ELSE NULL)

Comment: unfortunately the CASE statement was not ended properly. Please try now.

Comment: Thanks. The error now is Divide by zero error encountered.

Comment: This can be handled easily.

Comment: Yes, I will try null if

Comment: Thank you. Working as expected. Cheers